# How to include parent model inside child model through findAll query in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to include parent model within child model. However, I'm getting error 500. In the example below each `Brand` contains multiple `Jobs`.

**Model**

```
Job.belongsTo(models.Brand) 
Brand.hasMany(models.Job)
```

**Routes**

```
   models.Job.findAll({
      where: {
          job_archived_status: archived_status  
        },
        order: [ ['updatedAt', 'DESC'] ],
        include: [{
          model: models.Brand,
          where: {
            id: brand_id
          }
        }]
      }).  
      then(function(jobs) {  
          res.status(200).json(jobs);  
      }, function(error) {  
          res.status(500).send(error);  
      });
```

**Error**

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 98,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22P02",
        "position": "550",
        "file": "numutils.c",
        "line": "62",
        "routine": "pg_atoi",
        "sql": "SELECT \"Job\".\"id\", \"Job\".\"job_id\", \"Job\".\"job_archived_status\", \"Job\".\"createdAt\", \"Job\".\"updatedAt\", \"Job\".\"BrandId\", \"Brand\".\"id\" AS \"Brand.id\", \"Brand\".\"brand_name\" AS \"Brand.brand_name\", \"Brand\".\"brand_logo_url\" AS \"Brand.brand_logo_url\", \"Brand\".\"brand_archived_status\" AS \"Brand.brand_archived_status\", \"Brand\".\"createdAt\" AS \"Brand.createdAt\", \"Brand\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"Brand.updatedAt\", \"Brand\".\"ManufacturerId\" AS \"Brand.ManufacturerId\" FROM \"Jobs\" AS \"Job\" INNER JOIN \"Brands\" AS \"Brand\" ON \"Job\".\"BrandId\" = \"Brand\".\"id\" AND \"Brand\".\"id\" = 'null' WHERE \"Job\".\"job_archived_status\" = 'false' ORDER BY \"Job\".\"updatedAt\" DESC;"
    },
    "original": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 98,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22P02",
        "position": "550",
        "file": "numutils.c",
        "line": "62",
        "routine": "pg_atoi",
        "sql": "SELECT \"Job\".\"id\", \"Job\".\"job_id\", \"Job\".\"job_archived_status\", \"Job\".\"createdAt\", \"Job\".\"updatedAt\", \"Job\".\"BrandId\", \"Brand\".\"id\" AS \"Brand.id\", \"Brand\".\"brand_name\" AS \"Brand.brand_name\", \"Brand\".\"brand_logo_url\" AS \"Brand.brand_logo_url\", \"Brand\".\"brand_archived_status\" AS \"Brand.brand_archived_status\", \"Brand\".\"createdAt\" AS \"Brand.createdAt\", \"Brand\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"Brand.updatedAt\", \"Brand\".\"ManufacturerId\" AS \"Brand.ManufacturerId\" FROM \"Jobs\" AS \"Job\" INNER JOIN \"Brands\" AS \"Brand\" ON \"Job\".\"BrandId\" = \"Brand\".\"id\" AND \"Brand\".\"id\" = 'null' WHERE \"Job\".\"job_archived_status\" = 'false' ORDER BY \"Job\".\"updatedAt\" DESC;"
    },
    "sql": "SELECT \"Job\".\"id\", \"Job\".\"job_id\", \"Job\".\"job_archived_status\", \"Job\".\"createdAt\", \"Job\".\"updatedAt\", \"Job\".\"BrandId\", \"Brand\".\"id\" AS \"Brand.id\", \"Brand\".\"brand_name\" AS \"Brand.brand_name\", \"Brand\".\"brand_logo_url\" AS \"Brand.brand_logo_url\", \"Brand\".\"brand_archived_status\" AS \"Brand.brand_archived_status\", \"Brand\".\"createdAt\" AS \"Brand.createdAt\", \"Brand\".\"updatedAt\" AS \"Brand.updatedAt\", \"Brand\".\"ManufacturerId\" AS \"Brand.ManufacturerId\" FROM \"Jobs\" AS \"Job\" INNER JOIN \"Brands\" AS \"Brand\" ON \"Job\".\"BrandId\" = \"Brand\".\"id\" AND \"Brand\".\"id\" = 'null' WHERE \"Job\".\"job_archived_status\" = 'false' ORDER BY \"Job\".\"updatedAt\" DESC;"
}
```

Comment: what's the error ? and can you post full model definitions

Comment: @feiiiiii I've posted the error message in the description.

Comment: type error on line 62 .

Comment: @feiiiiii Line 62 is `res.status(500).send(error); `